# Some questions about Prism navigation in WPF

Tags: prism

I thought that if you registered a view with the IoC container as "Singleton" then the same instance would be reused each time you navigate to it, while registering the view as "Transient" would create a new instance each time you navigate to it. Unless I'm doing something wrong, I've found that the IoC "lifestyle" makes no difference, and it's the `IRegionMemberLifetime.KeepAlive` property that dictates whether the view is re-used or recreated each time. Is this correct? (I'm using Castle Windsor IoC).

When Prism documentation talks about a view being "deactivated", is this simply the process of hiding the view when it is navigated from? And if `KeepAlive=False`, does the view get disposed at this point?

What about nested views/regions? If a view contains a region with another view inside of it, and I navigate away from the parent view, do both views get deactivated/destroyed (depending on the value of `KeepAlive`)? What about `ClearChildViewsRegionBehavior` - where does this fit into things?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this apply to your situation but I implement the interface INavigationAware.
If a view should be reused for every navigation I always return true from the IsNavigationTarget method.

```
public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I just stumpeled upon a Prism article which had some information regarding your question. Have a look at step 3b:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165376/A-Prism-4-Application-Checklist